# Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load (login page and all other pages) in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, router-outlet

In the `app.component.html`, I have put a condition to decide which kind of template to use :

```html
<div *ngIf="_appService.titleName !== 'Login'">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div ngIf="_appService.titleName === 'Login'">
    <login></login>
</div>
```

I'm trying to redirect a user to the main page of the application once he's logged in. To do so I use this:

```ts
this._appService.titleName === 'Main page';
this._router.navigate(['/']);
```

By using this I get this error :

```ts
Cannot find primary outlet to load 'MainComponent'
```

This is disturbing me because I do the exact same thing the other way for logout (redirecting from main page to login page) and it works all fine.

I read some similar answers, but none of them helped me so far, because I don't want to add a `router-outlet` tag in my `login.component.html` since the main page is not a child component of the login one.

I think my problem is that I should use two `router-outlet`s instead of the login selector, but I cannot get it to work properly.

**My `app.routing.ts` :**

```ts
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path:'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'main',
        component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path:'',
        redirectTo:'/main',
        pathMatch:'full'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: ''
    }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: what is your expectation ?

Comment: I want a different layout for the login page and the rest of the app. I achieved that with the *ngIf. But when I want to redirect from the login page to any other page, I got an error as if no router-outlet could be found.
I would like to make this redirection works.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `this` in your template:

```
<div *ngIf="_appService.titleName !== 'Login'">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div ngIf="_appService.titleName === 'Login'">
   <login></login>
</div>
```

Comment: True, it was a copy/paste mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use named router outlet

```html
<div *ngIf="_appService.titleName === 'Login'">
    <router-outlet name="login"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and route

```ts
{
    path:'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    outlet: 'login'
},
```

For more info see [how to add a secondary route](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#add-a-secondary-route).

Comment: I tried, but it seems to break everything since my guard isn't working anymore, I cannot go to the login page at all and the url doesn't update correctly in the browser address bar.